# reactive environment within reactiveValues (RShiny)

Tags: shiny, reactive

I am trying to build a matrix with reactive dimensions that I want to update using an observeEvent expression. My idea was the following:

First, I am creating a reactiveValues object with a matrix of dimensions input$length (--> reactive) and input 0. Then I am using observeEvent with actionButton to trigger an update in the matrix. This entails updating a specific cell in the matrix, indicated by a reactive index vector (ind()), with a reactive value (value()).

I understand the problem: within mat = ... I cannot use another reactive expression, however I don't have an alternative solution and would very much appreciate any input on this.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Julian

---

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("length", "Dimensions of the matrix", value = 5),
  numericInput("a", "value for a", value = 2),
  numericInput("b", "value for b", value = 2),
  numericInput("ind1", "value for index vector 1", value = 1),
  numericInput("ind2", "value for index vector 2", value = 1),
  actionButton("go", "Update"),
  tableOutput("matrix")
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  ### Calculate the value that will be used for the update
  value <- reactive(
    mean(rbeta(100, input$a, input$b))
  )

  ### Create a reactive index vector used to determine the position of the cell in the matrix
  ind <- reactive(
    c(input$ind1, input$ind2)
  )

  ### Create reactiveValues matrix with dimensions specified in length
  beta.matrix <-  reactiveValues(
    mat = matrix(0, input$length, input$length)
  )

  ### Update matrix at positon ind with new value
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    beta.matrix$mat[ind()[1], ind()[2]] <- value() 
  }
  )

  ### Render matrix
  output$matrix <- renderTable({
    mat <- beta.matrix$mat
    mat
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need two reactive "stages" here.

1. initialise an empty matrix when the dimensions change
2. react on changes to the content of the matrix

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("length", "Dimensions of the matrix", value = 5),
  numericInput("a", "value for a", value = 2),
  numericInput("b", "value for b", value = 2),
  numericInput("ind1", "value for index vector 1", value = 1),
  numericInput("ind2", "value for index vector 2", value = 1),
  actionButton("go", "Update"),
  tableOutput("matrix")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ### Calculate the value that will be used for the update
  value <- reactive(mean(rbeta(100, input$a, input$b)))

  ### Create a reactive index vector used to determine the position of the cell in the matrix
  ind <- reactive(c(input$ind1, input$ind2))

  beta.matrix <- reactiveValues(mat = NULL)
  beta.matrix.ini <- reactive({
    mat = matrix(0, input$length, input$length)
  })

  observe({
    beta.matrix$mat <- beta.matrix.ini()
  })

  ### Update matrix at positon ind with new value
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    beta.matrix$mat[ind()[1], ind()[2]] <- value()
  })

  ### Render matrix
  output$matrix <- renderTable({
    mat <- beta.matrix$mat
    mat
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```